# Accessing Local Media File to Play in FlowPLayer

Tags: apache, jsf, richfaces, media, flowplayer

I want to access local media file say .mp4 file to play in FlowPLayer on Firefox browser..

My application is based on JSF and RF3.3 with JBoss server.

Problem is in my backing bean say I have written a file name as test.mp4 and the same is being present in WEB-INF folder..FlowPlayer will access this file using:-

http://IP/ContextPath/WEB-INF/test.mp4

But now say suppose I have a file placed in my D: drive on my system. The local server is running on my system.I want to access the file kept in D: drive and play it in flowplayer...

FlowPlayer always append http://IP/ to the file name and as such it won't play the media file..

Is there any way out to allow flow player to access local file on the system...

I figured that it can be done using Apache...But how/??...

Answer (score 0):

The component accepts a URL that must be accessible from the client browser, thus a url like `file:///C:/resources/foo.mp4` would not work.  The resource file you are trying to reference must be accessible from a web context.  That is not to say that you can't store the file resources on the D: of your machine, but you would need a web server like Apache to access that folder location as a web context folder.  It can be configured to do this, but I will not go into the details of how to do this, if you have trouble with that then you should post a question to the [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) StackExchange site for help with this.

One thing to keep in mind is that your web application is likely configured that any resources within the `WEB-INF` folder of your project is likely set to be the context path of your application.  Thus if you you were to place your MP4 file in your web app (i advice against it, those files are enormous), then it would be accessible from `http://site:port/applicationcontext/resources/foo.mp4` but on disk it is `WEB-INF/resources/foo.mp4`.

The best way that I set this up is to set up an Apache front end that is listening for web traffic on the specific port, then using the `mod_jk` module you can have Apache forward requests for resources at `http://site:port/applicationcontext/` to your application server on the AJP port.  I like this setup because I can keep large static resources at the ROOT context of the web server, as well as protect my application server by keeping it completely behind a firewall and inaccessible from the outside.  The application server can only be accessed through the Apache web server meaning increased security.  For more information on this type of setup, see this example guide on how to setup Apache Web Connector with Tomcat.  http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html

Comment: I do understand that I cannot access local files from the browser.Morever it is highly unsafe even if it does that..I heard a bit about Apache thing..Your reply helped me understand a bit more in detail about using AJP port for requests generating from the media page and forwarding that request to mod_jk and then to local drive..I will surely give it a try to understand and implement the said thing..I am a bit naive in this context and really appreciate any further comment/help from your side.

Comment: BUT one thing which probably requires more clarification.Will putting up a mod_jk and forwarding my request for media to AJP allow Apache to access media files present on local and play it on my browser.In this case will it be efficient to convert media data into object and stream it on browser...I found this to be very resource consuming....

Comment: @Hukamanata I still think you are a little confused.  Apache will serve the `.mp4` file from root context.  Tomcat will serve files (.jsp, .jsf, .html, etc...) from application context **THROUGH** Apache.  Apache gets request for application context JSP file, mod_jk is setup that it forwards this request to Tomcat through AJP port.  Tomcat returns JSP file, with a URL that points to .mp4 file in ROOT context.  The browser will see the URL for .mp4 file and make a **second** request to Apache to get .mp4 file from ROOT context.  Tomcat and web application does not have cont...

Comment: ... cont the .mp4 file, Apache does so Apache serves the file to the browser.  You could convert the file to an object and stream it to the browser but you are right that is very resource consuming and is not a good solution.  This is the most efficient way.  I hope this makes sense.